# how to retrieve the type of value which is there more number of times in a column in a table and count of it?

Tags: php, mysql

```
s.no    Name       type of vehicle allotted

1      ram             bus
2      krish           car

3      raj             bus

4      albert          car

5      johnson         bike

6      raghu           car
```

consider this is a table now i want to retrieve the type of vehicle which is there more number of times in the table and count of it. is there any particular method(query).

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)`, `GROUP BY` to get the count of each type, and `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT` to find the highest one.

Comment: @Barmar   .. ok  .. answer  removed

Comment: try to understand the question @Barmar

Comment: And what is your expected output.?

Comment: @SureshSarika The question is very poorly worded. I understood it to be asking to find the type of vehicle that has the most rows in the table.

Comment: i made it clear in the question, i will repeat it again, output : car(3)    car is there in the table more number of times and its count. @wanderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use COUNT and GROUP BY.
Count will give you the number of rows grouped by type field.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count, type FROM table_name GROUP BY type
```

The output should be like this:

```
count  |  type

2      |  bus
3      |  car
1      |  Bike
```

If you need just the highest one, append to the query:

```
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to `count` and select the top 1 row.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.* FROM(
    SELECT `type`, COUNT(`type`) `count`
    FROM `your_table_name`
    GROUP BY `type`
)t
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 1;
```